# Spring Security 5 Oauth configuration with external clientName parameter and ThymeLeaf

Tags: spring, security, oauth-2.0

Our app has a controller mapping ("/newsociallogin") that takes a request param String type (i.e. "google" or "apple") from an external site and then tries to automatically authorize based on standard property configs, etc. I need to configure a way that is smart enough to read the type param from my initial mapping and move forward. Also note that we have ThymeLeaf enabled, so each controller method has to either return a valid template/html or a redirect. I don't want to redirect to any actual page until I get the response from the provider which invokes a mapped redirect-uri.

This is what I have so far:

```
@GetMapping(value = "/newsociallogin")
    public ModelAndView newInitiateLogin(@RequestParam(value = "type") String type,
                                      HttpServletResponse response) {
        log.info("Get request to /newsociallogin with type: {}", type);
        ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView("redirect:/oauth_login?type=" + type);
        return modelAndView;
    }

 @GetMapping("/oauth_login")
    public ModelAndView getOauthSocial(@RequestParam(value = "type", required = true) String clientName)  {
        log.info("KP: in getOauthSocial, clientName = " + clientName);
        if (clientName != null) {
            return new ModelAndView("redirect:" + authorizationRequestBaseUri + "/" + clientName.toLowerCase());
        } else {
            return new ModelAndView("redirect:/");
        }
    }

 protected void configureLocalSecurity(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

        generateAppleClientSecret();
        http.sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.IF_REQUIRED);
        http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers(
            "/",
            "/oauth_login",
            "/newsociallogin/**"
        ).permitAll()
                .and()
        .oauth2Login().defaultSuccessUrl("/loginSuccess")
                .authorizationEndpoint()
                .baseUri("/oauth_login");


        http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/**").authenticated();
        http.exceptionHandling().authenticationEntryPoint(new LoginUrlAuthenticationEntryPoint("/"));
        http.logout().logoutSuccessUrl("/").permitAll();

        http.csrf().csrfTokenRepository(CookieCsrfTokenRepository.withHttpOnlyFalse());
        http.csrf().ignoringAntMatchers("/apple", "/registerwithsocial", "/updateapple", "/registerapple");
    }
```

The issue is communicating the incoming "type" param appropriately downstream and configuring the security properly.

I can't see when I inspect the Network flow that the call to /oauth2/authorization/google actually did anything.

Comment: I have considered writing an "auto submit" html that will forward to google/apple similar to the mapping above, but still need the type in scope somehow.